# How to create a column that evaluates the output in 3 other columns in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've the following data frame (df).

| GovKeepSecure | BankKeepSecure | OtherKeepSecure | Secure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| No | No | Yes | No |
| No | Neutral | Yes | Neutral |

I'm looking to write a python function that evaluates the first 3 columns, and returns the value that occurs more than 2 times in the "Secure"/4th column.

For example, if there's 2 or more of "No"s in the first 3 columns (in the same row), than the value in the "Secure" column results in "No." If such a condition isn't fulfilled, then the "Secure" column defaults to "Neutral."

I was wondering how we'd go about creating such a function.

Here's the approach I'm trying to develop.

```
import pandas as pd

def secure(row):
    if row["GovKeepSecure", "BankKeepSecure", OtherKeepSecure] == ["Yes", "Yes", "Yes"]:
             return "Yes"
    if row["GovKeepSecure", "BankKeepSecure", OtherKeepSecure] == ["Yes", "Yes", "No"]:
             return "Yes"
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------(etc.)
df["Secure"] = df.apply(lambda row: secure(row), axis=1)
```

Do let me know if there's a better way. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.select` for that

```
a = df[['GovKeepSecure', 'BankKeepSecure', 'OtherKeepSecure']]

yes_counts = a.eq('Yes').sum(1)
no_counts  = a.eq('No').sum(1)
df['Secure'] = np.select([yes_counts > no_counts,
                          yes_counts < no_counts],
                         ['Yes', 'No'],
                         default='Neutral')
```

---

You can also use `mode`

```
a.agg(lambda s: s.mode() if len(s.mode()) == 1 else 'Neutral', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# apply value_counts and take idxmax along a row
# sort values, as when value count are equal, it takes the first value in the series
# sorting helps makes neutral comes as first result

df['Secure']=df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().value_counts().idxmax() , axis=1)
df
```

```
    GovKeepSecure   BankKeepSecure  OtherKeepSecure      Secure
0             Yes              Yes              Yes         Yes
1              No               No              Yes          No
2              No          Neutral              Yes     Neutral
```

alternately,

```
# when multiple values has the same mode, take from the first column, 
# which is also sort and returns neutral

df['Secure']=df.apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0], axis=1)
```

Comment: why `sort` before `value_counts()`? Does it guarantee the order after `value_count` is applied?

Comment: when Yes, No, Neutral are all one, like as in last row. NO being the first value, is returned in idxmax. Sorting bring Neutral on top in that case